# Joining 4 tables and assigning default rows

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I have the following 4 tables:

**STORES:**

```
id     |    name
------------------
1         Store 1
2         Store 2
3         Store 3
4         Store 4
5         Store 5
6         Store 6
```

**ITEM_TYPES:**

```
type   |  description
----------------------
*A           *All (Automatically all stores would have this item) 
*SP          *Store_Specfic (Only a specific store would have this item)
T            Toys
H            Home
P            Pet
```

**STORES_ITEM_TYPES:**

```
STORE_ID   |  ITEM_TYPE
------------------------
1                T
1                P
3                T
5                T
5                H
5                P
```

**ITEMS:**

```
ITEM_NAME           |       SPECIFIC_STORE_ID       |   ITEM_TYPE
--------------------------------------------------------------------
CAT                            NULL                       P
BROOM                          NULL                       H
LEGO                           NULL                       T
BATTERY                        NULL                       *A
GIFT CARD                      NULL                       *A
PARROT                         NULL                       P
STORE2 ONLY ITEM                2                         *SP
```

I want to output all the items for every store:

```
STORE_NAME    |  ITEM_NAME     |      ITEM_TYPE    
-------------------------------------------------
STORE1              BATTERY              *A
STORE1              GIFT CARD            *A
STORE1              LEGO                 *T
STORE1              CAT                  *P
STORE1              PARROT               *P

STORE2              BATTERY              *A
STORE2              GIFT CARD            *A
STORE2              STORE2 ONLY ITEM     *SP

STORE3              BATTERY              *A
STORE3              GIFT CARD            *A
STORE3              LEGO                 *T

STORE4              BATTERY              *A
STORE4              GIFT CARD            *A

STORE5              BATTERY              *A
STORE5              GIFT CARD            *A
STORE5              CAT                  *P
STORE5              PARROT               *P
STORE5              BROOM                *H

STORE6              BATTERY              *A
STORE6              GIFT CARD            *A
```

So what is happening? I have some stores. I have some items. Those items have a type. For example, `LEGO`, is an item with a type of toy. There are some items that have a "special" type. These are prefixed with a '*'. The `*A` type stands for "all". This means this item should be in every single store. There is also the type `*SP` which says this item should only be in one specific store and that store is indicated in the `ITEMS` table.

The query I am trying to do is to show all the items each store has.

The problem I am facing is the STORES_ITEM_TYPES table doesn't specify the special types (*A and *SP). This is because these types are assumed inherently already be part of all the stores, so they don't need to be specified (this is not my data model).

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   stores p, 
       stores_item_types t, 
       items r, 
       item_types y 
WHERE  stores.store_id = stores_item_types.store_id 
       AND stores_item_types.item_type = items.item_type 
       AND stores_item_types.item_type = item_types.item_type
```

I am getting all the items EXCEPT the special ones (*A and *SP). So my output is currently like so:

```
STORE_NAME    |  ITEM_NAME     |      ITEM_TYPE    
-------------------------------------------------
STORE1              LEGO                 *T
STORE1              CAT                  *P
STORE1              PARROT               *P

STORE3              LEGO                 *T

STORE5              CAT                  *P
STORE5              PARROT               *P
STORE5              BROOM                *H
```

Here is a sqlfiddle:  [sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cae02d/1](https://%20sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cae02d/1)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry ???. What further detail is needed? I don't understand your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: The previous version of this answer tried (rather clumsily) to get around the limitations of the unusual data model. I think the following one is a better, clearer, approach.

The main issue here is that the data is not exactly normalized, especially with regards to the association between a store and an item type. My suggestion is to use two subqueries to obtain a clearer version of `stores_item_types` and `items`, and then make simple `INNER JOIN`s.

Let's start with `stores_item_types`. We want our derived table to say explicitly that each store also carries the `*A` type, and that each store also carries *its own* `*SP` type. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM stores_item_types sit
UNION
SELECT store_id, '*A'
FROM stores
UNION
SELECT store_id, CONCAT('*SP', store_id)
FROM stores
```

will produce something like this:

```
STORE_ID    ITEM_TYPE
1           *A
1           *SP1
1           P
1           T
2           *A
2           *SP2
3           *A
3           *SP3
...         ...
```

and so on. We also need a derived version of `items`, to match the new types `*SP1`, `*SP2`, etc.

```
SELECT
  item_name,
  specific_store_id,
  CONCAT(item_type, IFNULL(specific_store_id, '')) item_type
FROM items
```

The final query would then look like this:

```
SELECT
  s.name store_name,
  i.item_name,
  i.item_type
FROM stores s
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM stores_item_types sit
  UNION
  SELECT store_id, '*A'
  FROM stores
  UNION
  SELECT store_id, CONCAT('*SP', store_id)
  FROM stores ORDER BY store_id, item_type
) sit ON s.store_id = sit.store_id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    item_name,
    specific_store_id,
    CONCAT(item_type, IFNULL(specific_store_id, '')) item_type
  FROM items
) i ON i.item_type = sit.item_type
ORDER BY s.store_id, sit.item_type
```

You can see this query in action in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/489e89/44).

Comment: Thanks for the reply and explanation! Unfortunately, I only have read access to the database. Although it would require a simple insert, from an organization standpoint changes to the data are not easily done. So unfortunately I need to find a way with the way that STORES_ITEM_TYPES' data remains untouched.

Comment: Understood, just edited my answer with a workaround for that.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, it doesn't quite seem to work. I have created a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cae02d/1 . The Store Specific seems to be working in a weird way. On row 8 you can see the store_item_type and item_type are different. In my actual dataset, the Store Specific items seem to be repeating within the store

Comment: Good point about the repetition. I edited the last join slightly to exclude matching with store_id  = 0. The fact that store_item_type and item_type are different, though, I believe is normal. The first is telling you the base type of the store, the second is the actual type of the item.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding something sorry, but it seems for this to work, in the fiddle the stores_item_types must have the "0" record, but I, unfortunately, cannot change this data.

Comment: I have also updated the fiddle. I added an item to store 1 only and in the result, it shows up 3 times. I don't think I explained the result well enough. I am just interested in a list of the items in each store, the item types each store is associated with I am not interested in, if that makes sense?

Comment: My apologies, I clearly needed to rethink the problem. I will be rewriting my answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if it meets your expectations,

I have used union all to differentiate 3 different `item_types`

***First union:*** for those where we have matched items in `stores_item_types` and exculde others like `*A` and `*SP`.

***Second union:*** for only `item_type = '*A'` and did a cross join with all available store ids.

***Third union:*** for only `item_type='*SP'` and join with store id to include to the specific store.

```
select *
  from
(
-- for all matched items in store_item_types
select st.id,st.name,it.item_name,it.item_type
  from stores st
  join stores_item_types sit
    on st.id = sit.store_id 
   and sit.item_type not in ('*A','*SP')
  join items it
    on sit.item_type = it.item_type
  join item_types ity
    on sit.item_type = ity.type
union all
-- item type *A for all stores 
select st.id,st.name,it.item_name,it.item_type
  from stores st
  cross join items it
     on it.item_type = '*A'
union all
-- specific items for specific store
select st.id,st.name,it.item_name,it.item_type
  from stores st
  join items it
    on it.specific_store_id = st.id
where it.item_type = '*SP'
) a
order by id,case item_type
              when '*A' then 1
              when 'H' then 2
              when 'P' then 3
              when 'T' then 4
              when '*SP' then 5
              else 6
            end;
```

Note: the extra order by I put for my convenience to see the output which can be removed. And I have only taken columns which are necessary as per the expected output and others can be added if required.

[Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a8102f8c3d3e77db5f0ca900bf90ec6a) for reference